# Microsoft speech recognition in Hindi for typescipt SDK

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

Not able to use Hindi for speech recognition

particularly if I had this line the code fails to compile

Language is Typescript

`speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "hi-IN";`

'speechConfig' was also declared here.

```
import * as sdk from "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk";

environment = environment
   
 key = this.environment.mskey;
 region = this.environment.msregion

const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(this.key, this.region);
speaker 
player

speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "hi-IN";

isInputValid:boolean = false

speechRecognizerAudioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromMicrophoneInput("default");
speechRecognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(this.speechConfig, this.speechRecognizerAudioConfig);
```

The language recognition is working for the default setting without any modifications. Once, I add the line the application fails to compile. The property is mentioned in Microsoft sdk page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Coming from a JS world, I was confused the way speechConfig variable is declared. Declaring it inside the another function made it work. ```switch(this.selectedLanguage) { 
        case "te": { 
            this.speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "te-IN";
            break;
        } 
        case "hi": { 
            this.speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "hi-IN";
            break; 
        } ```